# When can (or can't) a word have two trops?

Tags: number, trop-cantillation

I sometimes see a single word having two *trop* marks, such as a *munach* followed by a *zakef katan*.  Usually, of course, words have only one (or are joined to other words and share one, sometimes).

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16483/472) to a question about a *shalshelet* says, in part:

> 1) Because it is the first word on the pasuk and deserved a zakef. At this distance from the etnachta, this would be a segolta. But a segolta needs a preceding zarka, and this is the first word. And so it becomes a shalshelet.

Setting aside the specific case (this is not a question about *shalshelet*), the well-supported answer there says that the *trop* it should have isn't available because it's not preceded by another.  But maybe it could have been, because a word can sometimes have two *trops*.  But maybe it can't have the *right* ones, or can't have them *at that position in the sentence*, or something else.

Hence my question: what are the rules governing when a word may, must, or must not carry more than one *trop*?  Are only certain combinations even possible (and if so, which)?

My knowledge of *trop* is somewhat basic.  I know how to *lein* it (or at least I think I do) at a basic level.  I know that a *pasuk* is usually broken into two parts separated by a "semicolon" like an *etnachta*, and I know the main "*trop* families" (e.g. what a full *etnacha* or *zakef katan* looks like and what sometimes drops out). I know about conjunctive vs disjunctive *trops*; if there are gradations within those, or other categories of *trop*, I don't know those.  I don't know much formal theory.

Comment: Note a _trop_ is an accent, and even in English an iamb or trochee is generally considered more natural than a spondee.

Comment: In short, the times you see multiple trop on one word are ([almost!](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56145/759)) always such that all the non-final ones are conjunctive (you can't pause in the middle of a word!). Regarding the Shalshelet case, Segol as a pattern must be preceded by Zarka but Zarka is itself pausal (albeit, a weaker pause than Segol, though that isn't relevant here) so we would need a second word.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks, that helps.  In the cases I remember, those additional non-pausal *trops* could also just be dropped, in terms of the *trop* family.  For instance, is a *munach* ever required?  Is there some rule saying to put the extra *trops* on the word in some cases, or is it case-by-case and there's no overarching rule?

Comment: Also, just to state what will be obvious (at least in retrospect): the word has to have at least three syllables, two of them with long vowels, or else there would be no way to have two emphasized syllables.

But most cases of "two trops" on a word are really two symbols denoting one trop.

Comment: @MichaBerger That's not always true, eg. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A0_%D7%99%D7%96 (it's often true, I grant you)

Comment: @MichaBerger you're right; in retrospect at least three syllables is obvious, and I hadn't thought about it explicitly.

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.20.31 (a once in Tanakh exception) EDIT: discussed in http://www.hum.huji.ac.il/upload/_FILE_1371624311.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The rules are complicated, but three of the more obvious explanations are (*a*) [the syllable preceding the tone is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UlCZ.png); (*b*) [the word is compound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV2rV.png), and/or (*c*) [elongated words will require extra cantillation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sQkd.png) for the purposes of fuller melody.

**Reference:**

Wickes, William (1887). *[Two Treatises on the Accentuation of the Old Testament](https://www.logos.com/product/27085/two-treatises-on-the-accentuation-of-the-old-testament)*. Oxford: Clarendon Press, *passim*.